# I keep getting Error CS0029

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error:

> CS0029    Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Renderer[]` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.Renderer>`

The code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AssignShadersToChildren : MonoBehaviour
{
    private new GameObject renderer;

    public Shader shader; // This should hold the Shader you want to use

    void Start()
    {
        // We create a list that will hold all the renderers(objects) 
        // so we can then assign the shader
        List<Renderer> renderers = new List<Renderer>();
        renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

        // For every Renderer in the list assign the materials shader to the shader
        foreach (Renderer r in renderers)
        {
            r.material.shader = shader;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method `GetComponentsInChildren` is probably returning `Renderer[]` instead of `List<Renderer>`

Comment: What is the problem with that error? You have the wrong type. You also create a throwaway list. Change the type of `renderers` to the correct one and remove the creation of a list.

Answer (score 2):

The error is descriptive. You need to convert the results to a List:

```
renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>().ToList();
```

Or change the local variable to be an array:

```
Renderer[] renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just enumerate the items?

```
void Start()
{
    foreach (Renderer r in GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
        r.material.shader = shader;
}
```

the only thing that's matter is that `GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>()` should return `IEnumerable<Renderer>` whatever it is (array, list...)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply omit the type and let the compiler do the work! There is no need to create a new list if you are then assigning the result of a method call to the `renderers' variable.

```
void Start()
{
    var renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    foreach (Renderer r in renderers)
    {
        r.material.shader = shader;
    }
}
```